# How to make Elasticsearch aggregation only create 1 bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch, postman, kibana

I have an Elasticsearch index which contains a field called "host". I'm trying to send a query to Elasticsearch to get a list of all the unique values of host in the index. This is currently as close as I can get:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "hosts": {
        "terms": {"field": "host"}
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
"buckets": [
            {
                "key": "04",
                "doc_count": 201
            },
            {
                "key": "cyn",
                "doc_count": 201
            },
            {
                "key": "pc",
                "doc_count": 201
            }
        ]
```

However the actual name of the host is 04-cyn-pc. My understanding is that it is spliting them up into keywords so I try something like this:

```
{
"properties": {
    "host": {
        "type": "text",

        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword",
                "fielddata": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns illegal_argument_exception `"reason": "Mapper for [host.raw] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [host.raw] has different [index] values, mapper [host.raw] has different [analyzer]]"`

As you can probably tell i'm very new to Elasticsearch and any help or direction would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{
"properties": {
    "host": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this works after searching for host.raw field. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Elastic automatically indexes string fields as text and keyword type if you do not specify a mapping. In your example if you do not want your field to be analyzed for full text search, you should just define that fields' type as keyword. So you can get rid of burden of analyzed text field. With the mapping below you can easily solve your problem without changing your agg query.

```
"properties": {
  "host": {
    "type": "keyword"
    }
}
```